# Can xmonad make our often used functions available anytime?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

We have some functions needed to be called at any time and places.  For example:

```
(defun winG (qty pb ps)
    (- (* qty ps (- 1 SXF YHS)) (* 2 GHF) (* qty pb (+ 1 SXF))))

(defun winQ (qty pb ps)
    (- (* qty ps (- 1 SXF)) (* 2 GHF) (* qty pb (+ 1 SXF))))

(defun stopLoss (qty pb &optional (lossRate 0.02))
    (let ((tot (* qty pb (+ 1 SXF))))
        (format t "Stop Loss at:~$~%" (- pb (/ (* tot lossRate) qty)))
        (format t "Lost Money:~$(~d%)~%" (* tot lossRate) (* 100 lossRate))))

(defun div618 (p1 p2)
    (let ((ratio '(0. 0.191 0.236 0.382 0.5 0.618 0.809 1.))
        (price #'(lambda (r) (if (<= p1 p2) (+ p1 (* (- p2 p1) r)) (- p1 (* (- p1 p2) r))))))
        (if (<= p1 p2)
            (dolist (r (reverse ratio)) (format t "-------~3$   ~$-------~%" r (funcall price r)))
            (dolist (r ratio) (format t "-------~3$  ~$-------~%" r (funcall price r))))))
```

Now we use stumpwm which can load our functions once started and we can call those functions just by striking hot key to open its eval window at any time and places. It is VERY convenient.  However, the stumpwm is not VERY steady as xmonad.  So we want to use xmonad instead of stumpwm and we donot mind to implement those Common Lisp functions using haskell.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: These don't look like window-management functions; are you just asking how to start a {lisp,Haskell} REPL from xmonad?

Comment: The stumpwm is a complete CL envirionment. so you can connect to it and to any evaluation just like ordinary REPL.  And you donot need to start another REPL.  I just want xmonad call our functions not a complele REPL.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do this via something like this

```
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
    [ ((modm,    xK_F1     ), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf) --starts the terminal
    , ((mod4Mask,xK_F1     ), spawn "gvim" >> -- you can concatenate commands too
                              spawn "notify-send -t 1000 gVim" >> 
                              focusUrgent) -- or haskell functions
    , ((mod4Mask,xK_F2     ), spawn "lisp evaluate lispy function") 
    , ((modm,    xK_F3     ), haskellFunctionPortedFromLisp )]
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It works but nobody want to bind a key to each function. Because there are many functions.

Comment: you could try to use `ghci` for interactive stuff - you can set it up to load your functions in a module file.

Comment: The standalone ghci works but it is not integrated with xmonad. Maybe the box running xmonad have not installed haskell.

Comment: There is xmonad-extras, but it seems it is VERY hard to make it work :(